# elseif statement is not working?

Tags: php

I write a logic to round value based on fraction part value. When i execute this code, elseif block is not executed. Here is my code

```
<?php

    function roundRating($rating)
   {

    if($rating>=5 && $rating<0){
             $rating=0;
         }

        $a=(int)$rating/1;
        $b= $rating-$a;

        if(($b>=.1) && ($b<=.2)){
            $b=0;
            $rating=$a;
        }
        elseif(($b>=.3 && $b<=.4)|| ($b>=.6 && $b<=.7)){
            $b=.5;
            $rating=$a+$b;
        }
        elseif(($b>=.8) && ($b<=.9)){
            $b=1;
            $rating=$a+$b;
            $a=$rating;
        }
        else{}


         return $rating;       
   }

  echo  roundRating(3.3);
?>
```

for this value 3.3, the output should be 3.5. But currently it will return passed value 3.3 instead of 3.5. Kindly help me to find out the problem in the above code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked value of `$b`? Is it what you expect?

Comment: I check your functions, No conditions met for your value. [Online Check](https://3v4l.org/FUeWZ)

Comment: `$rating>=5 && $rating<0` is always false - use `or` instead

Comment: @Frayne Konok then his code will work. right or not - i don't now. But now all if statement maybe removed at all

Comment: @FrayneKonok The first if-statement is just plain wrong, because `$rating` can never be greater than or equal to 5 and less than zero at the same time!

Comment: Also `$a=(int)$rating/1;` --> a number divisible by 1 is always the original number, so not sure what that line of code is trying to achieve.

Comment: @splash58, You got a good point. It must be `OR`.

Comment: @Mantis Team, the reason for this $a=(int)$rating/1; is i am splitting whole  value. I want to print the star based on whole value. Assume my $a vlaue is 3, i want to print 3 full yellow shaded star and my $b value is .5 i want to print half yellow shaded star.

Answer (score 1):

I've done my own version of the function which might be cleaner, and i think generates the output required:

```
 function roundRating($rating) {
    if( $rating > 5) {
          return 5; // Note: assuming the >5 case of 0 was a bug and it was meant to cap it to 5
    } elseif( $rating < 0 ) {
          return 0;
    }

    $number = floor($rating);
    $remainder =  $rating * 10 % 10;

    if( $remainder <= 2 ) {
      return $number;
    } elseif( $remainder >= 8 ) {
      return $number + 1;
    } else {
      return $number + 0.5;
    }
  }

  echo roundRating(3.4); // 3.5
  echo roundRating( 3.0) ; // 3
  echo roundRating( 6) ; // 5
  echo roundRating( 3.8) ; // 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the following code given bellow.we some times face problem in floating value comparison. So, it is useful to specify how much number we will consider after decimal point. In the following code value of b is specified that  it takes only 3 numbers after decimal point.

For details please visit: 
[is-floating-point-math-broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

To check online please visit:
[Online check](https://3v4l.org/FM4r2)

```
    function roundRating($rating)
   {

    if($rating>=5 && $rating<0){
             $rating=0;
         }

        $a=(int)$rating/1;
        $b= sprintf('%3f',$rating-$a);

        if(($b>=.1) && ($b<=.2)){
            $b=0;
            $rating=$a;
        }
        elseif(($b>=.3 && $b<=.4)|| ($b>=.6 && $b<=.7)){
            $b=.5;
            $rating=$a+$b;
        }
        elseif(($b>=.8) && ($b<=.9)){
            $b=1;
            $rating=$a+$b;
            $a=$rating;
        }
        else{}


        return $rating;       
   }

   echo roundRating(3.3); // 3.5
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers have hidden/limited precision in C - so you can't trust them to the last digit. There's more of a writeup on this at http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

If you were to round it to 1 decimal place, you'll get 3.5:

```
$b= round($rating-$a, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with below code.

```
<?php

    function roundRating($rating)
    {

        if($rating >= 5 && $rating < 0){
            $rating=0;
        }
        else
        {
            $a=(int)$rating/1;
            $b= $rating-$a;
            echo $a ."</br>";
            echo $b."</br>";
            if(($b >= 0.1) && ($b <= 0.2)){
                $b=0;

                $rating=$a;
            }
            elseif(($b >=0.3 || $b<=0.4) && ($b>=0.6 || $b<=0.7)){
                $b=.5;
                $rating=$a+$b;
            }
            elseif(($b>=.8) || ($b<=.9)){
                $b=1;
                $rating=$a+$b;
                $a=$rating;
            }
            else{}
        }

        return $rating;       
    }

    echo  roundRating(3.3);
?>
```

Here i have did two change first add else condition your rating calculation work if $rating  is not greater than 5 or less than 0. and second in one of your else if condition is change which is given below.

```
elseif(($b >=0.3 || $b<=0.4) && ($b>=0.6 || $b<=0.7)){
           //echo "here";
            $b=.5;
            $rating=$a+$b;
        }
```

i hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

To start with :

```
if($rating>=5 && $rating<0)
```

will always be false . A `variable` can't be greater than 5 and less than 0 at the same time.

Regarding

```
elseif(($b>=.3 && $b<=.4)|| ($b>=.6 && $b<=.7)){
        $b=.5;
        $rating=$a+$b;
    }
```

what practical differece would it make with :

```
elseif(($b>=.3 && $b<=.7)){
        $b=.5;
        $rating=$a+$b;
    }
```

unless you write :

```
else{
     $rating+=some_value;// forthe inifinite number of values between .4 & .6?
}
```

Regarding,

```
elseif(($b>=.8) && ($b<=.9)){
        $b=1;
        $rating=$a+$b;
        $a=$rating; // This statement is redundant
    }
```

Since you return `$rating` from the function, `$a=$rating;` is redundant.

Having said the above things, I feel below would be a much simpler implementation, with results almost identical to desired one :

```
<?php
function round_rating($rating){

    if($rating<0 || $rating>5){
        $rating=0;
        return $rating;
    }
    $t_rating=(int)$rating; //$t_rating short for trimmed_rating :)
    $dif=$rating-$t_rating; //$dif is the short for difference :)

    if($dif <= .2){
        return($t_rating);
    }
    elseif($dif <= .7){
        return((float)$t_rating+.5);
    }
    else{
        return((float)$t_rating+1); 
    }
} // round_rating function ends here :)

 /*Test time*/

 printf("Round rating for %0.2f : %0.2f\n",6,round_rating(6));
 printf("Round rating for %0.2f : %0.2f\n",0.2,round_rating(0.2));  
 printf("Round rating for %0.2f : %0.2f\n",1.4,round_rating(1.4));      
 printf("Round rating for %0.2f : %0.2f\n",2.8,round_rating(2.8));
 printf("Round rating for %0.2f : %0.2f\n",4.6,round_rating(4.6));
 printf("Round rating for %0.2f : %0.2f\n",-1,round_rating(-1));        

?>
```

Output :

```
Round rating for 6.00 : 0.00
Round rating for 0.20 : 0.00
Round rating for 1.40 : 1.50
Round rating for 2.80 : 3.00
Round rating for 4.60 : 4.50
Round rating for -1.00 : 0.00
```

Comment: You got a point, but here is another problem, there are several `if`, `else if` statements, there is the possibility to meet more than one statement true at the same time. So need a return on each conditions. I make a answer with checking all of them.

Comment: @FrayneKonok : I am on it pal.. Will be back shortly..:)

Comment: @FrayneKonok No two conditions in the original code can be true at the same time..

Comment: My head stuck doing these and some other work, so i can't figure out why these not work, so i quite.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers. Finally i got the answer. Here is my answer.

```
function roundRating($rating)
   {
   if($rating>5 ){
        $rating=0;
        return $rating;   
    }
    elseif($rating<=0)
    {
        $x=0;
        return $rating;   
    }
    $a=(int)$rating/1;
    $b= $rating-$a;

    $b= (int)round(($b*10),0); 

      if($b<=2)
      {
          $rating=$a;
            return $rating;   
      }
      elseif($b>=3 && $b<=7){
          $rating=$a+.5;
            return $rating;   
      }
      elseif($b>=8){
          $rating=$a+1;
            return $rating;   
      }
      else{}
}


echo roundRating(3.2); //3
echo roundRating(3.3); //3.5
echo roundRating(3.7);  //3.5
echo roundRating(3.8); //4
```